# Laravel Elixir watch not working properly

Tags: php, laravel, gulp-watch, pyrocms, laravel-elixir

So when I create a new Laravel project, gulp watch worked very perfectly. Now I'm working on PyroCMS project which is also used Laravel and the gulp watch kinda fails. I don't know why. 
It seems to have a problem with watching multiple sass files at the same time. It does not watch at all. However, with one sass file, it works perfectly.
Here is my code:

```
var sassPath    = './addons/dscms/anomaly/generali-theme/resources/sass/',
    cssPath     = './addons/dscms/anomaly/generali-theme/resources/css/',
    jsPath      =   './addons/dscms/anomaly/generali-theme/resources/js/',
    jsCopyPath      =   './addons/dscms/anomaly/generali-theme/resources/js/my-js/';

elixir(mix => {
mix
.sass([
    ''+sassPath+'main-style.sass',
    ''+sassPath+'section1.sass',
    ''+sassPath+'section2.sass'
    ], ''+cssPath+'main.css')
.scripts([
    ''+jsPath+'main.js',
    ''+jsPath+'main-2.js',
    ''+jsPath+'main-3.js'
],''+jsCopyPath+'main.js');
});
```

It also work with multiple js files but not sass files. Please help me with this one. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry for that. That was completely my fault :) The syntax was a little bit wrong there. The correct code is like this

```
mix
.sass(''+sassPath+'*.*', ''+cssPath+'main.css')
```

and I tested it. It watched multiple files and concatenated into one file. Worked perfectly!